# Click on prev/next link and fadein image on source change and retain container dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slideshow, fadein

I have a few images and I load them in a specific div when I click a prev/next link. The images loop. When I click the prev or next button, the JS change the source of the image, and load the next one. The code works.

And now my problem. 
I want to fade in every new image when it is fully loaded, to achieve a nicer effect and I'm not able to make it work. The code I put together from various sources works only for the first image.

I really want the code to be simple, because my knowledge of Jquery is really basic. I've searched the site and I find a lot of similar problems and solutions, but none worked for me.

**ADDED 10. oct. 2012:** @jbabey gave a good answer for my basic question (see below), but then another problem came up. When I click the nex/prev button and the new image is waiting to be loaded (and fade in) the container of the image shrinks. I understand that this is because the new image is hidden until it's fully loaded. But is there a way to change the JS, that it "remembers" the container height of the first loaded image (the basic image that loads on page load). So when I click prev/next the container of the image retains the height of the previous image. I can't set the height of the container, because of the page design.

Any help would be appreciated.

The original functions:

```
// Next image on button (and image) click
$('#swapnextimg,#imgId').click( function() {
    curIdx = (curIdx+1) % max;
    $("#imgId").attr('src', imgSrcBase+images[curIdx]+'.jpg');
});

// Prev image on button click
$('#swapprevsimg').click( function() {
    curIdx = (curIdx+max-1) % max;
    $("#imgId").attr('src', imgSrcBase+images[curIdx]+'.jpg');
});
```

**Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/S_Ajd/6vHSb/**

**@jbabey's code: http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/6vHSb/28/**

Answer (score 1):

Just take the code you wrote to fade in the first image and put it in the click handlers for the previous and next buttons.

```
// Next image on button (and image) click
$('#swapnextimg,#imgId').click( function() {
    curIdx = (curIdx+1) % max;
    $("#imgId").hide().attr('src', imgSrcBase+images[curIdx]+'.jpg')
    .load(function () {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});

// Prev image on button click
$('#swapprevsimg').click( function() {
    curIdx = (curIdx+max-1) % max;
    $("#imgId").hide().attr('src', imgSrcBase+images[curIdx]+'.jpg')
    .load(function () {
        $(this).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/6vHSb/28/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried something similar, but with a buggy code.

Comment: ... But now I see another problem, When I click the nex/prev button and the new image is waiting to be loaded (and fade in) the container of the image shrink. I undertstand that this is becouse the new image is hidden till is fully loaded. But is there a way to change the JS, that it "remembers" the container heigt of the first loaded image (the basic image that loads on oage load). So when I click prev/next the container of the image retain the heigt of the previous image. I can't set a heigt of the container, becouse of the page design.

Comment: @S_Ajd that would be a different question :) if this answer helped, feel free to upvote and/or accept it so that future visitors know which solution works.

Comment: Well thanks. I will edit my question  and add the new problem. I cant upvote, becouse I don't have enough points.